# how to process tcpdump outputs in c

Tags: c, linux, tcpdump

I am trying to write a c code to leave tcpdump running while my program is active and then in real-time getting the tcpdump output into my code for further processing. I am capturing a very specific traffic (I have been able to acheive that in cmd) and I want to get the information of each captured packets in real-time into my code in order to process them. It is expected that these packets I am capturing come every 10-20 seconds, which means that I need to run tcpdump and every 10-20 sec I get the information into my code and process them.

An ideas on how to do that please?

Comment: good questions; i know there are online resources but i would lke to see what the community has to say

Comment: Use libpcap, see http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

Comment: Ok, I am dealing with ipv6 packets and looking for tutorials and examples on using libpcap to process ipv6 packets but I could not find any as most of them considering ipv4 only, is any one aware of any ipv6 examples or how process ipv6 packets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to analyze captured packets in real-time you should not run and parse tcpdump output, but use the underlying API/library directly: Which is libpcap.

See http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

Comment: Ok, I am dealing with ipv6 packets and looking for tutorials and examples on using libpcap to process ipv6 packets but I could not find any as most of them considering ipv4 only, is any one aware of any ipv6 examples or how process ipv6 packets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256821/can-i-use-pcap-library-for-receiving-ipv6-packets